# Mapping a mouse button to another mouse button

Tags: mouse, remapping

I want to change one of the side buttons of my Logitech MX Master 3 to pressing the scroll-wheel down. I need it to work all the time, not just at button press (I want to be able to "drag" with it, very handy for CAD). I checked the buttons with xev, so I need to map button9 to button2.
Using xbindkeys:

```
"xte 'mouseclick 2'"
    b:9
```

This does not at all work for me, I have to add the modifier "Release", but then it does not register holding down.
I am using Plasma KDE, X11.

Is there a way to achieve a complete remap?

Comment: This may differ between Wayland and Xorg. Thus, provide information about the desktop environment you use. If using standard Ubuntu, see on the "About" panel whether you run Wayland (the default) or Xorg.

Comment: I am using Plasma KDE, X11

Comment: Use "edit" to update your question. That information belongs there.

Comment: Does this help your question? [Input Remapper](https://askubuntu.com/a/1491915/1450948)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using piper to do the same thing.