# How do I map Ctrl+Shift+Win+X to Delete key?

Tags: gnome, shortcuts, xkb

I already have defined `Ctrl+Shift+Win+Q` for closing window, but this was done using `Gnome-Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts`, now I want to map `Ctrl+Shift+Win+X` to Delete button for working with software, where I use mouse with my right hand and some shortcuts with left one.

Is it possible to do with xkb-options or some other way?

Comment: You can remap or add a new shortcut using this software [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1491915/1450948). Let me know if it helps

Comment: @Ajay Didn't help...