# Trouble changing Control_R to Shift_L

Tags: keyboard, 22.04, xmodmap

I have trouble changing my right control to left shift. The solution I had working in 18.04 was `xmodmad /home/kameranis/.Xmodmap` with the following contents.

`keycode 105 = Shift_L`

After upgrading to 22.04 that solution no longer works. Using `xev` I can see that the change has been registered, but in all applications it still works as the right control key. Also tried using Input Remapper and it did not work. Any ideas on what might have changed?

```
KeyPress event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x1200001,
    root 0x498, subw 0x0, time 1808734, (142,163), root:(229,314),
    state 0x10, keycode 105 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 50
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x1200001,
    root 0x498, subw 0x0, time 1808835, (142,163), root:(229,314),
    state 0x14, keycode 105 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 50
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Comment: I hope this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1491915/1450948) will help with your question.

Comment: Already tried using Input Remapper and it did not work. I am guessing that something ignores the keysym.

Comment: are you on Wayland? what's the output of `echo "$XDG_SESSION_TYPE"` in terminal?

Comment: Yeap, wayland
```echo "$XDG_SESSION_TYPE"
wayland```

Comment: see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/292868/how-to-customise-keyboard-mappings-with-wayland)