# How can I make the music buttons on the keyboard do copy and paste?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, xdotool

I want single-button shortcuts for copying and pasting. I never use the music buttons I have on my keyboard (Logitech k540), so I decided to use them.

How can I do this?

(I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS)

I have created custom shortcuts that have "Audio previous" and "Audio next" as their shortcut. I have installed xdotool and have given `xdotool getactivewindow key ctrl+c` and `xdotool getactivewindow key ctrl+v` as their commands, respectively.

Like so:

[image: screenshot of custom shortcut dialog]

But it doesn't work. When I press the respective buttons, all I get is a ⦸ symbol  at the bottom of my screen for a few seconds. Nothing is copied, nothing is pasted.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Does [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1491915/1450948) answer your question??

Comment: @Ajay Yes! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the comment helped you solve the issue, I am adding that [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1491915/1450948) here.

You can use the "**Input Remapper**" software in Ubuntu which provides a **GUI** and recognizes keys that are not recognized by `xbindkeys`, `xinput`, etc.

### Installation

**Command line:**

```
sudo apt install git python3-setuptools gettext
git clone https://github.com/sezanzeb/input-remapper.git
cd input-remapper && ./scripts/build.sh
sudo apt install -f ./dist/input-remapper-2.0.1.deb
```

**GUI:**

You can find the software in the **Software Center** (or **App Center**) on Ubuntu.

[image: app-center-screenshot]

### Interface

In the GUI, the software will list all the devices that are connected to your PC.

After selecting your device, you will get a window to edit your keys. There you have to add:

- **Rename**: Add a name to the mapping profile and press the down-arrow button on the right
- **Add**: Use that button to create a new keymap for your profile. You may need to Stop the injection if you have already set up mapping before.
- **Record**: Use this button after selecting your new key binding and record your keys.
- **Output**: You can edit the output of your new input on the right side of the window. You can refer to the project's [Usage](https://github.com/sezanzeb/input-remapper/blob/main/readme/usage.md)  section for several key inputs.
- **Apply**: Click on this button and also turn on the Autoload so that the profile gets activated once the software starts.

Also, don't forget to add this software to the **Startup application** along with enabling the **Autoload** option so that it will automatically map the key once you log in to the system.