# I'm trying to remap some keys + Rctrl to act as the arrow keys but for some reason I can't use autokey

Tags: remapping, keys

I use a 60% keyboard that doesn't have the arrow keys and while I was using Windows I remapped them using <kbd>RCtrl</kbd> + some other keys.

Now on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS I'm trying to fix this problem.
For some reason I can't use AutoKey (the application doesn't recognize any keys when I press it).

I don't know if this would be a problem but in the Brazilian keyboard I'd like to remap the <kbd>ç</kbd> key + <kbd>RCtrl</kbd> to the up arrow.

The file I was using on Windows had the following content:

> RCtrl & SC027:: Send {Blind}{RCtrl up}{Up}
>
> RCtrl & .:: Send {Blind}{RCtrl up}{Left}
>
> RCtrl & `;:: Send {Blind}{RCtrl up}{Down}
>
> RCtrl & SC073:: Send {Blind}{RCtrl up}{Right}
>
> Where SC027 is 'ç' and SC073 '/'

I'm not familiarized with ubuntu so any advice is welcome

Comment: Does this answer your question: [input-remapper](https://askubuntu.com/a/1491915/1450948) ??