# I don't want to use mouse and I only have a 75% keyboard which dosen't have keypad. Is it possible?

Tags: keyboard, remapping, mouse-keys

I am running ubuntu 23 rn. I turned on the default keyboard key accessibility settings(not fully sure, but I think there is an option for the non-keypad users to use number keys as mouse keys by holding the Fn key).
But the problem is that I don't even have the Fn key. I wanted to remap it to the pagebreak key that I don't use. But I am confused about how to do it or if it's possible or not because I read in some places that the fn key connects with the hardware, it's not software-related. Actually, I am confused. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What is Ubuntu 23 rn??  There is Ubuntu 23.04 Desktop, Ubuntu 23.04 Server, Ubuntu 23.10 Desktop, Ubuntu 23.10 Server as well as other *flavors* etc.. so which are you asking about?  The Ubuntu Core systems that use the *year* format (eg. Ubuntu Core 22) only release on *even* years, so none in 2023.

Comment: Does [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1491915/1450948) answer your question??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remap this key to backspace?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1490352/remap-this-key-to-backspace)